# Why does returning the same value yielded from a generator suppress PyLint error E0106 "Return with argument inside generator"?

Tags: python, return, generator, yield, pylint

I am trying to trigger PyLint Error E0106 "Return with argument inside generator".

The following triggers the error.

```
def tokenize(string):
    for token in string.split(' '):
        yield token
        return "I ruin everything."

for t in tokenize("This sentence has five tokens."):
    print t
```

PyLint output:

```
************* Module tokenize
C:  1,0: Missing docstring
E:  4,0:tokenize: Return with argument inside generator
C:  1,0:tokenize: Missing docstring
```

The following does not trigger the error.

```
def tokenize(string):
    for token in string.split(' '):
        yield token
        return token

for t in tokenize("This sentence has five tokens."):
    print t
```

PyLint output:

```
************* Module tokenize
C:  1,0: Missing docstring
C:  1,0:tokenize: Missing docstring
```

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-Bit

Python version: 2.7.3

Output from `pylint --version`:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 0.25.0, 
astng 0.23.0, common 0.57.1
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
```

Comment: What does it say about `return string`?

Comment: Both versions of your code give me a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.7 (in the actual interpreter, not in PyLint). They're both valid in Python 3.3+, as a return value can be used in a generator (it will be the value of a `yield from` expression on the generator).

Comment: @minitech When substituted with ``return string`` the error is still not triggered. I assume that you wanted me to experiment with returning the argument that was passed to the function.

Comment: @Bickknght I can confirm that also. Thanks for testing. I should clarify that I'm not actually trying to execute this code. I'm just running it through PyLint. So in that regard do we just attribute this to a bug in PyLint?

Comment: @KayceBasques yes this is due to some bug in pylint. Actually two: you get incoherent behaviour because of static inference limitation, leading to the message being displayed in one case but not in another; also, this construction is now allowed with python 3.3 and so no error should be reported anyway in that case.